# The following team project collection is stopped ... Start the collection and then try again

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

**Background:** We have an azure DevOps pipeline that we use to automatically deploy a webapp we maintain to an azure test instance.

This suddenly stopped running today with the following error.

> TF24668: The following team project collection is stopped: ***********. Start the collection and then try again. Administrator Reason: abuse

where *********** is our project name.

[image]

It fails instantly when this happens.  It doesn't appear to do anything else other than throw this error.

The developer who initially got the pipeline set up is no longer with the company.

I've looked through the DevOps interface, and I can't find what it means by this "project collection", and I can't find out how to start it.

Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: Are you running Azure DevOps Server on-prem?

Comment: This happens on Microsoft Hosted Instances as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bug with azure that they fixed within a few days

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Pipelines:-errorTF24668:-The-f/1239940

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Azure DevOps Service**. This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Pipelines:-errorTF24668:-The-f/1239940?preview=true) on Azure DevOps, Microsoft Product Team has fixed it and all hosts have reboot, you could try it again and then kindly share the result here.

If you are using **Azure DevOps Server**, you should open **Azure DevOps Server Administration Console**->click the tab **Team Project Collections**->check the collection and ensure the state is **Online**, then try it again.

**Note**: If you do not have enough permission to do this, please contact the collection administrator to check it.

[image]

Comment: It was the known issue you mentioned in the first paragraph.  It's not happening right now

Comment: We are using Azure DevOps Service (so: hosted by Microsoft, not self hosted except a custom agent) and are experiencing this issues since yesterday

Comment: We are facing a similar issue since morning. Worked perfectly alright throughout the day yesterday.

Comment: We are also facing same issue.

Comment: Hi all, Open the project settings->Parallel jobs, and check the the number of Parallel jobs.

Comment: You are using public project or private project, If we create new projects in new Azure DevOps organizations, we will see the number of Public Parallel jobs is 0, then we could see the error message, check this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/)  for more details.

Comment: Faced this issue since last night. The pipeline that ran the other day. Release pipeline, same error. No fix currently found. No Parallel job running and private project.

Comment: Same issue is reported with an organization in west europe region.

Comment: Same issue in a newly created organization in the west european region. Pipeline wont run at all.

Comment: I have faced this issue. And cannot find the option to start the project collection in the azure portal. I am using azure devops cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same and reported an issue on [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/) and got the following response

> We had some bad actors using our MS-HOSTED pipelines pools in ways they should not have been, and we blocked them in order to maintain the stability of Azure Pipelines.

Full response can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-following-team-project-collection-is-stopped-s-3/1362999#T-N1363189)

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as it might sound there is an [Azure DevOps Dashboard](https://status.dev.azure.com/) that states health of Azure DevOps services. I got his error on Wednesday where status of pipeline service in my region was marked as **degraded**. On Thursday status changed to **healthy** and my pipeline works!